# Getting button_to to act like link_to - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have a `button_to` call that I essential want to act like a `link_to` call. I set it up to use a `get` request but when I click it, in the URL a '?' appears on the end of the URL. 
Ex: `/admins/new?` instead of `/admins/new`. How do I remove this ? from the URL so it behaves just like a `link_to` link?

Button_to code

```
<%= button_to "New Admin", new_admin_path, :method => :get %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your own question:

[image]

The red arrow points to elements that look like a button but in fact are links, just styled. You can do the same in your app.

Comment: Haha, your absolutely right! I can't believe I was that stupid. Thanks for pointing out the obvious!

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the method in button_to like such:

```
<%=button_to "Admin",new_admin_path,{method: :get}%>
```